# Can't get Eclipse to display my custom console

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

**Edit**: A bit of debugging gives me the following message:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/console/IConsoleFactory**

I think it is because of this reason why the plugin does not load my class.

I am creating a custom console for displaying some generated data in my Eclipse plugin. Here is the required code:

```
<extension
  point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consoleFactories">
 <consoleFactory
     class="HandlersAndSelectionView.CustomConsole"
     icon="icons/final_icon.gif"
     label="Equivalence Check Results">
 </consoleFactory>
</extension>


import org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsolePlugin;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleFactory;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleManager;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole;

public class CustomConsole implements IConsoleFactory { 
public void openConsole() {
    IConsoleManager consoleManager = ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager();
    MessageConsole console=new MessageConsole("My Custom Console",null);
    consoleManager.addConsoles( new IConsole[] { console } );
    consoleManager.showConsoleView(console);
    }         
}
```

The problem is although I can see my custom console name in the console drop-down, nothing happens when I click on it. How do I display it?  (Note that the code inside the openConsole() method is just for debugging, copied from SO itself).

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is an error message about this. Is `HandlersAndSelectionView` really the package name for this class? You should stick to the Java conventions of using all lower case for package names.

Comment: Yes sir, that is the package name. I'll change it once I roll-out the final plugin. I'll have a look at the log file as soon as I have access to my system.

Comment: @greg-449 When I click on the custom console in the drop-down list, the following error appears: **HandlersAndSelectionView.CustomConsole cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleFactory**

Comment: You are not referencing the IConsoleFactory interface correctly. Have you done something like copying any of the plugin jars?

Comment: @greg-449 I didn't get you. Yes, the plugin does need external jars to some tasks. They have been copied to  folder named lib, which in-turn is in the project.

Comment: You must not copy plugins to a lib folder. All plugins must be referenced using `Require-Bundle` or `Import-Package` in the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: Really? Till now, I used to do the following: 1. Import external libraries by going to the project properties. 2. Add the libraries to a "lib" folder in the project. 3. Add the folder to the "build.properties" file. 3. Add the libraries to the classpath in the Manifest.MF. What might be the problem I might face with this method?

Comment: External non-plugin libraries are different from plugins. You must reference plugins the way I said, copying plugins will not work.

Comment: I am not copying plugins, but only external jars. To be specific, the Apache Commons Maths library.